# Traversing a dictionaries predecessors

Tags: python, dictionary

Without libraries or any imports:

Given a dictionary

```
a = {(9,9): (1,0), (9,8): (1,1), (1, 0): (9, 8), (9,8): (1,1), (1, 1): (0,0)}
```

I want the output to be [(0,0), (1,1), (9,8), (1,0), (9,9)]

Without hard coding it. So it could be {(nx, ny): ... , .... , : (0,0)}. Basically it starts at (0,0) appends it to the list then takes the key appends that, and so on.

Comment: Why is your dict backwards, though? If you want to go from `(0, 0)` to `(1, 1)`, you should store that as `(0, 0): (1, 1)`, not the other way round...

Comment: It looks like you are traversing from value to key to the next value. This means you need to do lookups of values, which is slow, instead of keys, which is fast. You would be much better off if you swapped keys and values here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this line:

> Basically it starts at (0,0) appends it to the list then takes the key appends that, and so on

Use:

```
a = {(9,9): (1,0), (9,8): (1,1), (1, 0): (9, 8), (9,8): (1,1), (1, 1): (0,0)}
[item for sublist in [[v, k] for k, v in a.items()][::-1] for item in sublist]
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (9, 8), (1, 0), (1, 1), (9, 8), (1, 0), (9, 9)]
```

Comment: The question says without importing any modules. Not sure if itertools can be used.